# How to retrieve only those records that do not have an associated record?

Tags: php, cakephp, associations, cakephp-3.0, query-builder

I am using **CakePhp 3.x** and i am trying to filter data on the bases of associated data.
Let suppose i have two models **Users** and **Profiles**

Users Has-one Profile and Profiles belongs to a user.

so i want to get those users who haven't profile so kindly help me how can i apply the conditions ?

```
$this->Users->find('all',[
  'conditions'=>['Profile.id'=>Null]
])
```

I was trying like this i thing it is wrong and then i tried it with contain but contain makes filter on associated data not to the users so is there any way to get those user who have no profile ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the Link below :-

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#using-notmatching

There are three type of filtration of data on the bases of associated data.

1 -> **matching**

2 -> **noMatching**

3 -> See the Link above

**Matching**
This function will filters results that have relation to the specified association: for now it's profiles.

```
$this->Users->find()->matching('Profiles') //This will get those user how have profile
```

**NoMatching**

The opposite of matching() is notMatching(). This function will change the query so that it filters results that have no relation to the specified association:

```
$this->Users->find()->noMatching('Profiles') //This will get those user how have no profile
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
$query = $this->Users->find()
  ->contain([
    'Profiles' => function ($q) {
      return $q
        ->select(['id', 'name'])  // Your profile fields, say id, name etc.
        ->where(['Profiles.id' => NULL]);
   }
]);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: see this link http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-notmatching and thanks for the help.

Comment: @MuhammadAsifSaleem If you read that and can answer your question, please do so by posting the solution as an actual answer - thanks!